# How do I configure PyCharm to display JavaScript inside <script> tag to be highlighted like in *.js file?

Tags: pycharm

I have *.html file and `<script>` tag inside it, which contains JS Code.
JS Code displayed as raw text. How do I configure PyCharm to display JS Code inside `<script>` tag like in *.js file ( with proper CodeStyle highlighting)?

[image]

Comment: For me it did without any configuration. Can you get a screenshot how your file looks like?

Comment: Works for me also. Any chance your HTML has something malformed in it?

Comment: Nope, HTML is well formed. Do you have community edition of pyCharm?